# Should I use orchard in a complex web application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, orchardcms

My client wants to develop web app where **huge pieces of functionality will be added over the next 3 years**. And the product should be able to last for 10 years minimum.
I've suggested building the system in a very **modular** fashion.

There will have to be a base framework and a set of core modules for database abstraction, accounts and other things specific to the business logic of the company, and then use modular MVC-Areas for the large pieces of functionality that **depend** on the core business modules.
The application must support theming too.

I look at this and think  *"they want me to build a CMS."*
Great, so as I look at building functionality for all these things I see **Orchard** and think to myself *"This has everything a guy with a fetish for extensibility needs!"*

As good as orchard looks I am worried about relying on a 3rd-party framework, and any **gotcha's** I'll hit along the way, especially in years to come.

So I'll summarize my **points of interest:**

1. Would it be wise to use Orchard (or any other CMS) for this specific scenario? (must last ~10 years)?
2. Using this architecture I would need modules having dependencies to other "business core modules", does orchard support such a thing?
3. What are any possible gotcha's or limitations related to using Orchard in this fashion?
4. What are the different pro's and con's to using Orchard in this way vs. a complete design? Both from the client and developer perspective.

Comment: Take a look at BlogEngine with a view to converting it to a CMS ;-)

Comment: This is a request for discussion and opinion, and is off topic for StackOverflow. The [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) specifically mentions these types of question as being a poor fit for the design here. Voting to close as not constructive.

Comment: @KenWhite I am not attempting to promote discussion. I want subjective answers enlightened by experience with the topic. The three POI are definitive questions that can be answered with YES/NO.
However if you feel i should reword the question feel free to edit it.

Comment: "Do you think" and "Are you aware of possible gotcha's" are exactly that, and your entire question("Should I use orchard") is asking for opinion. The three questions that can be answered "yes/no" can be answered with exactly that: "Yes, you should use orchard" or  "No, you shouldn't use orchard" wit zero additional content, and that means it's not specific or concise. I'm not editing your question, because it's inappropriate here and rewording it won't change it to make it appropriate; it's entirely based on asking for discussion and opinion.

Comment: @KenWhite in regard to your last statement; you could do that with all Q on SO, usually that answer would get no upvotes and therefore be a bad answer. Thats why I ask the question in a 'discussive' (for lack of a better word) way so that I get a more verbose answer than YES/NO. I do not wish to argue the validity of my question, so if it is voted to close then so be it.

Comment: It takes two years to build a half-decent CMS. Your choice.

Comment: @BertrandLeRoy true. I'm not aiming to build a CMS, however I believe I would benefit from some CMS features

Comment: Well, Orchard is easy to integrate into if you know MVC... But "some CMS features" is hard to get without taking the whole app.